# Enter Discord Channel via Console

Tags: discord

Is it possible to enter a discord channel using the Dev Console (Ctrl + Shift + I)?

Something like "client.openChannel("channel_id")"
or a fetch that will load the channel?

More specifically this

[image: DMs]

but without having to have the user in friends or having the user ID.

With the user ID you can just use this

```
fetch("https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/channels", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "*/*",
    "accept-language": "en-US",
    "authorization": "mfa.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
    "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
    "x-context-properties": "",
    "x-super-properties": ""
  },
  "referrer": "https://discord.com/channels/@me",
  "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
  "body": "{\"recipients\":[\"USER_ID\"]}",
  "method": "POST",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "include"
});
```

And it'll open the DMs with that user but for some I only have the channel ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an exact answer but a workaround that should work in some cases.

I got all the channels IDs from the "Request my data" on "Privacy and Safety".

Once I got the channels IDs on `file.zip/messages/index.json` I grabbed all those IDs and called

```js
let channels = ['54623165841324165','54623165841324165','54623165841324165']
async function get_Channel_Data() {
  let channel_id = channels.pop();
  await sleep(2000);
  let response = await fetch("https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/" + channel_id, {
    "headers": {
      "accept": "*/*",
      "accept-language": "en-US",
      "authorization": "mfa.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
    },
    "referrer": "https://discord.com/channels/@me",
    "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
    "body": null,
    "method": "GET",
    "mode": "cors",
    "credentials": "include"
  });

  let data = await response.json();
  // data.type 1 is a DM, data.type 0 is server
  if (data.type == 1) {
    // This is the user ID of the person you DM
    console.log(data.recipients[0].id);
  }
  get_Channel_Data();
}
```

Then for each user ID call

```js
let user_ids = ['54623165841324165','54623165841324165','54623165841324165']
async function open_dms() {
  let user_id = user_ids.pop();
  if (user_id === undefined) {
    console.log("END");
    return false;
  }
  await sleep(2000);
  let response = await fetch("https://discord.com/api/v8/users/@me/channels", {
    "headers": {
      "accept": "*/*",
      "accept-language": "en-US",
      "authorization": "mfa.XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "content-type": "application/json",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
      "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin"
    },
    "referrer": "https://discord.com/channels/@me",
    "referrerPolicy": "no-referrer-when-downgrade",
    "body": "{\"recipients\":[\""+user_id+"\"]}",
    "method": "POST",
    "mode": "cors",
    "credentials": "include"
  });

  let data = await response.json();
  open_dms();
}
```

to open the DM with that user ID